# The LIKE operator in SOQL does not escape special character

Tags: salesforce, sql-like, soql

Hi below is my SOQL qoery

```
SELECT ID,Name, Dodge_Report_Number__c,Project_Name__c,Bid_Date__c,GC_Awarded__c,Action_Stage__c,Target_Start_Date__c,Project_Valuation_High__c,Project_Valuation_Low__c,Type_Of_Work__c,Removed_By__r.Name, Removed_By__r.LastName ,Removed_By__r.FirstName,Reason_Removed_Comments__c,Reason_Why_Project_Removed__c,Branch_ID__c FROM Dodge_Project__c WHERE Branch_ID__c != null AND CreatedDate >= LAST_QUARTER AND CreatedDate <= THIS_QUARTER AND Job_Profile_Status__c NOT IN('Created','Removed') AND Branch_ID__c IN('101','102','909','903','941','994','217','904') AND (Action_Stage__c IN ('Start','Construction') OR GC_Awarded__c = TRUE) and (Name like 'P@#$&(%' or Dodge_Report_Number__c like 'P@#$&(%' or Project_Name__c like 'P@#$&(%' or Action_Stage__c like 'P@#$&(%' or Type_Of_Work__c like 'P@#$&(%' or Removed_By__r.Name like 'P@#$&(%' or Reason_Why_Project_Removed__c like 'P@#$&(%' or Branch_ID__c like 'P@#$&(%') order by Name asc NULLS FIRST
```

I am getting an error like "Invalid character found in the filter value "P@#$&(%" used with the "like" operator".

If I write query like

```
SELECT ID,Name, 

Dodge_Report_Number__c,Project_Name__c,Bid_Date__c,GC_Awarded__c,Action_Stage__c,Target_Start_Date__c,Project_Valuation_High__c,Pro

ject_Valuation_Low__c,Type_Of_Work__c,Removed_By__r.Name, Removed_By__r.LastName 

,Removed_By__r.FirstName,Reason_Removed_Comments__c,Reason_Why_Project_Removed__c,Branch_ID__c FROM Dodge_Project__c WHERE 

Branch_ID__c != null AND CreatedDate >= LAST_QUARTER AND CreatedDate <= THIS_QUARTER AND Job_Profile_Status__c NOT IN

('Created','Removed') AND Branch_ID__c IN('101','102','909','903','941','994','217','904') AND (Action_Stage__c IN 

('Start','Construction') OR GC_Awarded__c = TRUE) and ( Project_Name__c like 'P@#$&(%' ) order by Name asc NULLS FIRST
```

It is working fine.

what is the issue?
thanks.

Comment: if I escape the "(" like "P@#$&\\\(" then, error is not coming, but if a record contains "(" character, it is not searching using Like query. I can`t use SOSL in my code.

Comment: if I escape the "(" like "P@#$&\\(" then, error is coming in like query,

Comment: First query returns records if a picklist value contains "(" of that record. for a normal text field, it is not returning the records though it has a "(" in it.